# Firebase CLI using a wrong service account despite being logged in to another

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I have recently started learning about building a serverless backend using Firebase for the cloud functions. I have been able to set up a Firebase project with some functions, which I would like to deploy. However, since I have previously logged in with another service account, it does not allow me to deploy despite the fact that I logout first and then login with the proper account.

I logout with `firebase logout`, which states `Logged out from ....@gmail.com`. Then I login with the proper account with `firebase login`, which opens my browser so that I can login with my account.
When I try to deploy with `firebase deploy` it throws an error

```
Missing permissions required for functions deploy. You must have permission iam.serviceAccounts.ActAs on service account previousAccount@appspot.gserviceaccount.com.

To address this error, ask a project Owner to assign your account the "Service Account User" role from this URL:

https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=previousAccount
```

I have also tried setting the proper account as the default one for the project directory, but that did not address the issue.

How can I erase the other service account and start using the proper one?